# Service settings through graphical interface

Tags: c#, .net, service

There is a service that has the DLL included. The library stores some settings (COM-port names, ip-adress) in the file App.Config. Question: how to allow the user to change these settings by hand? There is an idea to create a separate window application that would change the fields in the App.Config file. I would like to find the best solution.